# How to enable scroll of PS/2 mouse in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: ubuntu, mouse, scrolling

My mouse scroll doesn't work at all. There are other questions regarding mouse scroll, but not appropriate in my context. It used to work fine in Windows XP.

Answer (score 1):

Can you confirm that you have the following section in your `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file?

```
Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier  "Mouse0"
    Driver      "mouse"
    Option      "Protocol" "auto"
    Option      "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option      "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option      "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection
```

The key line in that stanza is the `ZAxisMappping`. That specifies that you have a scroll wheel and stipulates that it's implemented as buttons 4 & 5. Which is mechanically how the wheel works. scrolling down, triggers a "button press" of 4. Whereas scrolling up triggers a "button press" of 5.

Comment: I didn't find xorg.conf file.
Should I create it and and paste the code provided by you.

I will list the files in the section that you mentioned /etc/X11/
>>>>>>>>>
app-defaults             rgb.txt  Xreset      Xsession.d           Xwrapper.config
cursors                  X        Xreset.d    Xsession.options
default-display-manager  xinit    Xresources  XvMCConfig
fonts                    xkb      Xsession    XvMCConfig.dpkg-new

Comment: @Habi - I think you can generate one if you don't have it using this command: `sudo Xorg -configure`. Then copy it to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`.

Comment: I get this message>>>>>>>>>>>>
habi@habi-MS-7529:/etc/X11$ sudo Xorg -configure
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) Server is already active for display 0
 If this server is no longer running, remove /tmp/.X0-lock
 and start again.
(EE) 
(EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
  at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
(EE)

Comment: You can follow some of the steps here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/285571/ubuntu-13-04-fail-to-start-after-installing-nvidia-drivers-vostro-laptop. You don't need to do the nvidia ones, would be my guess.